# Excel VBA how to skip a sheet if isnt not in the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Ok blow is the code I have to this point. The issue i have relates to the below if. What can i do if the sheet im trying to select is not in the workbook? I would like to just skip if and move on not error out.

```
 If k = 1 Then
    Sheets(Key).Select
    IF
    End If

Start of full code

    Set xlWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FILEPATH)
    Y = xlWorkbook.Name
    Set xlWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Import)
    xy = xlWorkbook.Name


    Workbooks(Y).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select


    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$490").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"
    CP = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    For COUNTER = 1 To CP
    COMBO = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rowC).Value
    k = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & rowC).Value
    KEY1 = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & rowC).Value

    If k > 1 Then
    rowC = rowC + 1
    KEY2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & rowC).Value
    End If

    Workbooks(xy).Activate


    If k = 1 Then
    Sheets(Key).Select
    IF
    End If



    rowC = rowC + 1
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting a sheet that doesn't exist, Excell will throw an exception
You can handle on this exception by using `On Error`

```
On Error Goto label
```

or

```
On Error Resume next
```

Comment: It works fine the first time through but the 2nd time it fails when it cant find the sheet name.

Comment: Did you clear your error after handling it?  `Err.Clear()` should empty your error object (number and description).  To actually finalize your error handling, place the code `Resume Next`at the appropriate location in your code.